# How to generate automatic numbering that sent to email

Tags: php, html

First of all I'm going to tell a bit about myself. I have an adequate knowledge about HTML, CSS. For PHP, I just started to learn.

I'm building a website using Wordpress, and using Elementor. So in this Elementor plugin, there's a function to build form, capture it and sent to our chosen email.

Currently I want to build a registration page that contain a form. The form will contain basic requirement such as name, age, address etc. So when a person fills the form, it will automatically be captured by the system and sent to our chosen email.

The problem is, I want to put numbering to each registration made on the form sent to the email. Example: After a user has fill the form, I got an email stating that there was a new registration. I want in the headline or subject to have a registration number such as 'Registration No 221' , then the next user who gonna fill the form and the system sent it to us, will receive an email at his side stating that 'Your registration No is 222. Please wait for us to call you'. Meanwhile in our email, I want an email stating that 'New Registration Available: Registration No 222'. This is an automated email sent by the system.

I want to have fully control on how the registration number start. So I can change it to start at number 500, then reset it to another number such as 356 or something else.

I know a bit PHP but not too much. Is there any guide here how can I create this features? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please, read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question, so people can have more info about your problem.

Comment: You would most likely need a database to hold onto and increment this number.  I assume you would need a database anyways to hold onto the customer data they enter into the form.  PHP and MySQL are usually a good pair.  Just remembered you are using Wordpress which uses a MySQL database anyways.  Not sure if you can use that one or have to create a seperate database, but that is what you will need.

Comment: "start at number 500, then reset it to another number such as 356" but ... then you could get to 500 and over again.  You wouldn't want that ... right?  You probably want to ensure that you are assigning _unique_ numbers.

Comment: as @dmikester1 said, you need to store your number in the database to prevent duplication. i suggest to use a random number generator  script. you can create it , its simple. then attach the value at the subject of email to be sent.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what database you are using but I think would be best for you to create a table with an auto increment field and use that as your registration ID. This way you aren't in danger of re-using the same number for multiple users.

`mysql`
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html

`sql server`
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017

`postgres`
http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-serial/

Alternatively you could just create a number var in php and increment it each time registration occurs. That would give you the ability to change it whenever you would like, but could result in duplicates.

```
$regNum = 356;

function submitForm() {
    // code...
    $regNum++;
}
```

Comment: If there is nothing to persist that `regNum` variable, it will always be 356 on every form entry.  The database method using auto-increment is by far the best way to do this.

Comment: Agreed. I was just trying to provide an oversimplified example of how the OP could change the Registration Number at will.